# adding Route name in routes.insert function MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Hi I am creating a RouteBase object and try to insert in routes collection using route.insert 
`routes.Insert(0, objRoute);`method. How can i assign a name to the route in this scenrio??

like `routes.add("myfavroute", localizedRoute);` method

Info: I have to use the routes.Insert method as i have to ad the route at the top of the collection

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that you cannot provide a name if you use the `Insert` method to add the route. You will have to call the Add method before any other route registrations if you want this named route to be the first one.